# Need to Re Design existing logic for dynamic input

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a method `getFormattedValue(List<String> dataHeaders, List<String> data)` that returns String value based contents of dataHeaders and data list. dataHeaders list can have 10 distinct values and based on value at particular index output string formation changes.

Below code was working fine tiil the time when dataHeaders contents are received in specific order , but lately this order is changing many atimes. As this input is received from other app/ system, i do not have control over order of elements. Hence i want to update my code so that it works correctly even after input order is altered.

If 1'st element of dataHeaders list is "OPERATION_NAME" then i need not take any action, but if "OPERATION_NAME" comes at 2'nd index in dataHeaders list then i need to do special formatting to output value. And so on....

My Pain is that i receive 10 dataHeaders. Please suggest me any good approach to handle this issue. I am posting my code below, suggestions are welcome.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ValueGenerator {

    public String getFormattedValue(List<String> dataHeaders, List<String> data){

        String formattedOutValue=null;

        if(dataHeaders!=null && data!=null &&
                dataHeaders.size() == data.size()){
            if(dataHeaders.get(0).equals("OPERATION_NAME")){
                formattedOutValue=data.get(0); // Add no spaces
            }else if(dataHeaders.get(1).equals("OPERATION_NAME")){
                formattedOutValue=data.get(1)+"    "; // Add 4 blank spaces
            }else if(dataHeaders.get(2).equals("OPERATION_NAME")){
                formattedOutValue=data.get(2)+"      "; // Add 6 blank spaces
            }           

        }

           //likewise i want to avoid redundant if - else if check 


        return formattedOutValue;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want `data.get(2)` in the case of `dataHeaders.get(2)` and not `data.get(1)`

Basically you just need to find the index of the string `OPERATION_NAME` in `dataHeaders` and use it for `data`. The simplest way is to iterate over the list `dataHeaders` with an index and stop when you find it.

If you need to handle more strings then you could use a `Map` to map the strings you want to evaluate to their indices, this could look like this:

```
final static Map<Integer, String> formatByIndexMap;
static {
    formatByIndexMap = new HashMap<>();
    formatByIndexMap.put(0, "");
    formatByIndexMap.put(1, "    ");
    formatByIndexMap.put(2, "      ");
    // and so on
    formatByIndexMap.put(9, "----format for 10----");
}

public String getFormattedValue(List<String> dataHeaders, List<String> data){
    String formattedOutValue = null;
    if (dataHeaders != null && data != null && 
            dataHeaders.size() == data.size()) {
        Map<String, Integer> dhm = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < dataHeaders.size(); i++) {
            dhm.put(dataHeaders.get(i), i);
        }
        Integer operationNameIndex = dhm.get("OPERATION_NAME");
        if(operationNameIndex != null) {
            formattedOutValue = data.get(operationNameIndex.intValue()) + 
                    formatByIndexMap.get(operationNameIndex);
        }
    }
    return formattedOutValue;
}
```

The format map `formatByIndexMap` is defines as `final static`.

An for some basic testing:

```
@Test
public void getFormattedValue() {
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList("operation", "foo", "bar");
    List<String> dataHeaders;
    String formated;

    dataHeaders = Arrays.asList("OPERATION_NAME", "FOO_NAME", "BAR_NAME");
    formated = getFormattedValue(dataHeaders, data);
    Assert.assertEquals("operation", formated); // no spaces

    dataHeaders = Arrays.asList("FOO_NAME", "OPERATION_NAME", "BAR_NAME");
    formated = getFormattedValue(dataHeaders, data);
    Assert.assertEquals("foo    ", formated); // four spaces

    dataHeaders = Arrays.asList("FOO_NAME", "BAR_NAME", "OPERATION_NAME");
    formated = getFormattedValue(dataHeaders, data);
    Assert.assertEquals("bar      ", formated); // six spaces

    dataHeaders = Arrays.asList("FOO_NAME", "BAR_NAME", "", "", "", "", "",
             "", "", "OPERATION_NAME");
    data = Arrays.asList("operation", "foo", "bar", "", "", "", "", 
            "", "", "tail");
    formated = getFormattedValue(dataHeaders, data);
    // ----format for 10----
    Assert.assertEquals("tail----format for 10----", formated); 
}
```

Comment: Yes that was typo, corrected it. My real problem starts once i know the index, as index number varies so does my logic to return formmated String. Instead of doing many if- else if's , i need some generic solution.

Comment: @DarkKnight I've edited the code to make it bit clearer. What do exactly mean by index varies? do you know the max number the index can have (you seem to, since you mention 10 data headers) ? If then then just put all your formats into the map by their corresponding index. If not then you could build the same map dynamically based on the size of your lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response, with index varies I mean to say that there can be max headers coming out of 20 or so predefined ones and each header has different value scheme based on its index.  With current approach we need to create 20 maps. Is there any other alternative to do it generically. Please suggest.

Comment: @DarkKnight, You could turn the map key to be a String and then extend it to include the header set and the index inside that header set, such a key could like this: `HeaderNumber+IndexNumber` and the value would be the format itself. Or have a map of maps where the key is `HeaderNumber` and the value is the map I have show above. You will have to identify the header set you actually have in order to build the key you need and either way you'll end up with same number of mapping for your formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot A4L, your opinion helped me a lot.